# Apple developer account name changing

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

A week ago I sent an email for apple asking to change the name (that I draw red circle around it in the attached image) but they didn't reply! please can any one of you tell me how to change it? And what do you call that name exactly, it's developer name or what?

[image]

I sent an email by this link:
https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit.php

Comment: It's the name of your company. Developer name can be found in the description below the screenshots of the app and it's different

Comment: Thank you for your replay, Do you know how can I edit my company name? @SergiusGee

Comment: You cannot edit your company name yourself.  Apple must update this for you.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, So how should I contact apple to change it? @bdrobert

Comment: I have used the same support form you referenced above and it took a number of days to receive a response.

Comment: You could try calling them at the appropriate number here: https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php

Comment: solution?? Which was the fastest process to accomplish this purpose? Thanks

Comment: @Frade Actually I forgot, Sorry. I hope you find a fast solution.

Answer (score 2):

That is the company name that you selected the first time you uploaded an app to your iTune's Connect account.  That is separate from the company name provided for your iOS Developer Program registration.  Apple is able to assist you in changing it, tho you may be limited in what they allow you to change it to.